# Using jQuery each function and $(this) to alter specific slideshow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am using jQuery UI and copying their 'Snap to Increments' slider, which can be found here http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps.

**Use**: Creating more than one slideshow per page. When the increment is changed an image on the slideshow will change (corresponding to that decibel level).

**Issue**: I have it working so that each "slider" is working separately, however I'm struggling to have the images change for individual sliders. For example, let's say I have two sliders on one page. If I slide the first slider the second one's images change as well, but the slider itself will not move on the second one. As you will see below in my code I am trying to use $(this) to ensure that only the slider being used responds.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    // $( ".slider" ).slider({
    $( ".slider" ).each(function(){
        $(this).slider({
        value:10,
        min: 10,
        max: 80,
        step: 10,
        animate: true,
        animate: "slow",
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            // line below: hides div that was previously selected from slide bar
            $('.decibelCtr > div').hide();
            switch(ui.value) {
                case 10:
                    // $('.decibel10').show();
                    $(this).closest('decibelCtr').children('.decibel10').show();
                    break;
                // etc
            }
            switch(ui.value) {
                case 20:
                    $('.decibel20').show();
                    break;
                // etc
            }
            switch(ui.value) {
                case 30:
                    $('.decibel30').show();
                    break;
                // etc
            }
            switch(ui.value) {
                case 40:
                    $('.decibel40').show();
                    break;
                // etc
            }
            switch(ui.value) {
                case 50:
                    $('.decibel50').show();
                    break;
                // etc
            }
            switch(ui.value) {
                case 60:
                    $('.decibel60').show();
                    break;
                // etc
            }
            switch(ui.value) {
                case 70:
                    $('.decibel70').show();
                    break;
                // etc
            }
            switch(ui.value) {
                case 80:
                    $('.decibel80').show();
                    break;
                // etc
            }
        }
        });
    });
});
```

I created a JSFiddle that has some of the HTML corresponding to this code. Found here: http://jsfiddle.net/ccm9n9fz/.

==============================================

Also, you can see I'm trying to use $(this) on the "10" decibel level, but haven't had success with this and other configurations.

I'm still a novice with jQuery so any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem with your code was the use of `closest`. `closest()` only looks for parents and using `$('.slider').closest("")` will return you **undefined or null** value as it wouldn't be able to fetch the element.

Instead of which you can pluck the previous element of the current div using,

```
$(this).prev(".decibelCtr").find('.decibel10').show();
        ^^ Gets Previous element with specified class
```

#### And here is the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccm9n9fz/2/)

Sorry, I am not good at explanation but I hope this will help you.

Comment: Correct you are sir and your explanation was perfect. I thought I was hitting the '.decibelCtr' with closest(). I'll have to be more careful in the future to make sure I'm hitting the right element. Thank you!